# would a run score from third with a man on second when the batter flied out and they tagged the base at second cause he left early

Tags: rules, baseball

With a man on third and second, batter flies out to right and is caught for the second out. The runner on third tags up legally. The runner on second left early, right field throws to third to get the runner on second going to third. He left early they throw to second and get the third out. Does the run from third count?

Answer (score 3):

The run would count, so long as it was the *preceding runner* (meaning, the one further ahead on the bases - in your case, the runner on third base).  See rule 5.09 (d) in the [MLB Rules](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf):

> (d) Effect of Preceding Runner’s Failure to Touch a Base
> Unless two are out, the status of a following runner is not affected
> by a preceding runner’s failure to touch or retouch a base. If, upon
> appeal, the preceding runner is the third out, no runners following
> him shall score. If such third out is the result of a force play, neither preceding nor following runners shall score.

5.08 (a) also makes this clear:

> (a) One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to
> and touches first, second, third and home base before three men
> are put out to end the inning.
> EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner ad -
> vances to home base during a play in which the third out
> is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first
> base; (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by a preceding runner who is declared out because he failed to
> touch one of the bases.

If the runner on *third* base did not tag, and then *both* runners scored, then the run from the runner on 2nd would not count if the third base runner's out was the third out in the half inning. However, the *second base* runner does not impact the *third base* runner, unless he is forced out before the runner on third base scores.

Comment: Yup.  I think the confusion on these is that some folks assume that any non-tag play (like an appeal) is a force, and therefore 5.08(a)(2) is relevant.

Comment: Nearly this exact question is described in a comment on the definition of a force play in the MLB rule book. The run counts if, in the umpire's judgement, the runner scored before the other runner is called out for not tagging up.